# Make dimension relative to another in React Native

Tags: image, layout, react-native

**The problem**

I'm working on an app in React Native and I need an image to have, i.e., its height as a certain percentage of the width.

[image: The background is an Image and I'd like its height with size relative to its width]

**The code**

In the picture, the background is an Image with another Image inside. I'm using styled components.

```
export const ImageWithButtonStyled = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  padding: ${Spacing.XLarge}
  alignItems: center
  width: 50%
`;

export const ImageWithButtonImageContentStyled = styled.View`
`;

export const ImageWithButtonBackgroundStyled = styled.Image`
  marginLeft: ${Spacing.Large}
  marginRight: ${Spacing.Large}
  backgroundColor: ${Color.GrayLight}
  borderWidth: 1
  borderColor: ${Color.Gray}
  justifyContent: center
  alignItems: center
  width: 100%
`;

export const ImageWithButtonButtonContentStyled = styled.View`
 alignSelf: stretch
 alignContent: center
`;
```

This is how they are being used in a component `render()` method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageWithButtonStyled>
        <ImageWithButtonBackgroundStyled source={null}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/ic_photo/ic_photo.png')}/>
        </ImageWithButtonBackgroundStyled>
        <ImageWithButtonButtonContentStyled>
          <LinkButton text={this.props.buttonText} />
        </ImageWithButtonButtonContentStyled>
      </ImageWithButtonStyled>
    );
  }
```

**What I'm looking for**

The result I'm looking for is this:

[image]

But without having to hardcode any dimension, just using percentages and setting the height as a percentage of the width, so that the gray box **maintains, in any screen, the aspect ratio that I define**, scaling accordingly. So, if i say that the height is 1.4 the width, that aspect will be maintained in any screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 0):

Because the values of width and height in the `react-native` is unitless and you can't use something like `width: 50%` you should use the `Dimension` in your app. You can get the dimensions of screen using code below and style your components with something like `width: width/2`

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
...
let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')
```

Comment: Thing is, % is not really an unit, it's the absence of, isn't it? Since it's (unit)/(unit). Perhaps that's why it's been working.
As much as your solution works, I'd like to set it directly in the style, otherwise, I'd be passing style to the component class, which I want to avoid. However, if there is no other solution...

Comment: You can use this `Dimension` anywhere you want, in `style` prop or in a `StyleSheet` object. Of course I should say that the best way to make a layout and styling is using `Flex`. You can read this link for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html